# Installing new Nuget packages failing in Azure (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, azure, nuget

I have installed via Nuget a bunch of packages to do with SendGrid. Locally, this all works flawlessly. However, once it's deployed and working, I get the following exception thrown:

```
Exception Thrown: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'SendGrid.SmtpApi, Version=1.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=55aa52d3c3c0d2b2' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name: 'SendGrid.SmtpApi, Version=1.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=55aa52d3c3c0d2b2' at SendGrid.SendGridMessage..ctor() at seshpicker.Controllers.AccountController.<ForgotPassword>d__18.MoveNext() WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I believe this may be because the new Nuget Sendgrid packages are probably not deployed. However, I do not know where they should go when they are live in Azure. I can't seem to find where all the other packages are stored either.

On my local machine, they are stored in the same directory as my visual studio solution file under a folder called packages. I have also included the references within the build.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

Basically, I had a much newer version of SendGrid.SmtpApi (1.3) than what the parent dependency was looking for.

Downgrading to the exception mentioned version solved this.